# php - sorting data from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
content1{id, var1, var2, var3, created_at}
content2{id, var1, created_at}
content3{id, var1, var2, var3, va4, created_at}
```

I have joined 3 tables but I would like to sort and display by created_at.
By joining tables, I get values from all 3 content, how do I churn data from only the content table that I need.
What is the best suggestion to do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you using Eloquent to fetch your data? What database software are you using?

Comment: Yes I am. Running off Sequel Pro in Mac @Scopey

Answer (score 1):

Custom declaration of fields in the join. And using inner join.
So

```
Select a.a, a.b ... etc ... innerjoin  b.a as a1, b.b as a2 ... etc ... on a.a = b.a
```

Then you get the possibility of sort by a1. For instance.

Answer (score 0):

you can do multiple join with on table.

where if required and than group by method as mention below

```
 $records = ModelName::select('table1.id','table1.var1')
                            ->join('table2', 'table2.id', '=', 'table1.id')
                            ->join('table3', 'table3.id', '=', 'table1.id')
                            ->where('table1.var2', '=', 1)
                            ->orderBy('table3.created_at', 'ASC')
                            ->get();
```

Comment: well it's not just created_at of table3. i have to take in account of table1 and table2 as well.